# Replacing a String value to a Map<String, dynamic> in a Map

Tags: json, dictionary, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following Dart code, which I use the retrieve data from my Firestore database:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> teamData = await _teamService.getTeamById(tournament["teams"][i]);
tournament["teams"][i] = Map<String, dynamic>.from(teamData);
```

The tournament is a map of a document from Firestore and originally it contains an array of document ids (the teams key-value pair). I'd like this code to query Firestore for the team with the original id and replace it's data with the id. The query is flawless, returns the correct map, but when it tries to replace the element, it throws this error:

> Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'LinkedMap<String, dynamic>'

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from the description what the type of `tournament` is. Or how it is defined.

But assuming tournament is something like this:

```dart
final Map<String, dynamic> tournament = {
  'teams': ['bobcats', 'wolves', 'ducks'],
};
```

The reason you cannot replace `'bobcats'` with a `Map<String, dynamic>` is that `'bobcats'` is contained within a `List<String>`. You can force the teams list to be `dynamic` by adding a type parameter, which would allow for elements of either `String` or `Map<String, dynamic>`.

```dart
final Map<String, dynamic> tournament = {
  'teams': <dynamic>['bobcats', 'wolves', 'ducks'],
};
```

You could also replace the original `List<String>` with a `List<dynamic>`, which maybe useful if you are not defining the value of `tournament` directly in the program, but getting it from a web service or somewhere else.

```dart
tournament['teams'] = List<dynamic>.from(tournament['teams']);
```

After that you should be able to assign whatever values you want to the list.

Comment: Thank you, the second version solved the issue. (btw, it was stated in the question that tournament comes from Firestore)